# Ionic prevent phone sleeping only when app is running

Tags: ios, cordova, sleep-mode

The [Insomnia](https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Insomnia-PhoneGap-Plugin/tree/47ba15a4ad791eb4d5a0643cdb7ef69f73109e15) plugin promises to keep devices awake with `window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake()`, until such time as `window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain()` is called.

But for some apps it only makes sense for the device to stay awake while the app is active. If the user pauses the app and forgets they have left it going in the background, it would be nice to allow sleep rather than decimate their battery level.

Typically actions required on app pause are handled through the `pause` event:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", onPause, false);
}

function onPause() {
    window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain();
}
```

But according to [Cordova docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/cordova/events/events.pause.html), the Pause handler on iOS can't call anything native - which would include the Insomnia plugin.

How to achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `allowSleepAgain()` with a `$timeout` and reinit the delay everytime you do something with `keepAwakeforMinutes()`.

```
var keepAwakeforMinutes = function(minutes){
    // when an action is done,
    // cancel the last allowSleepAgain() $timeout if exists to create a new longer one
    if ($rootScope.sleeping){
        // alert("cancel previous timeout");
        $timeout.cancel( $rootScope.sleeping );
    }

    // be awake for the next minutes by creating a new timeout
    $window.plugins.insomnia.keepAwake();
    $rootScope.sleeping = $timeout(function() {
        // timeout ended
        $window.plugins.insomnia.allowSleepAgain();
    }, 60000*minutes); // awake for the next minutes
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source of that plugin, on iOS it calls `setIdleTimerDisabled:true` on the `UIApplication` instance.  [`isIdleTimerDisabled`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplication/1623070-isidletimerdisabled) is

> A Boolean value that controls whether the idle timer is disabled for the *app*.

It doesn't disable the idle timer for the device as a whole, so if the user suspends your app then the idle timer will be enabled again.